# How do I cache nginx "location" (which result is dynamically generated by nginx) to reduce server load?

Tags: nginx, web-server, cache

I am using [nginx rtmp module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module). According to its [doc](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#statistics), I can retrieve statistics of connected clients. Here's my current setting:

```
http {
    server {
        listen 8080;
        location /stat {
            rtmp_stat all;
            rtmp_stat_stylesheet stat.xsl;
        }
        location /stat.xsl {
            root /usr/local/nginx/html/;
        }
}
```

Every access to "/stat" will cause the result page to be dynamically generated.

How do I actually cache the result? I mean, every requests will cause the result page to be dynamically generated. Instead, I'd prefer to receive the same result cached for up to a specified time, as to reduce the server load.

Comment: Have you tried using standard Nginx [page caching](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/)?

Comment: The "origin server" is not is not another middleware server, but the XSL parser within the nginx rtmp module itself. Will it work?

Comment: I have no idea, that's why I suggested you try it. Probably best not to do it in on a production machine.